# Using JS Interop from Dart server

Tags: dart, firebase

I am trying to create a Dart server that watches a Firebase path. There is a Firebase package in Pub, it is a wrapper for the Javascript library. The [instructions for installing the library](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-dart/) say:

> The firebase.js library MUST be included for the wrapper to work:

I can see how this would work with a client-side Dart application, but how can I use the Firebase Javascript library from a Dart server?

Comment: From having no idea about Firebase, I guess you can't use it on a server side. Because you don't have window/document properties.

Comment: You can use Firebase from the server. I have done so from Node and Rails servers. I'm just not sure how to get access to the js code from a Dart server. As far as I can see, the same issue would apply to any server-side js library.

Comment: If you can't use the JavaScript library, you can always talk to Firebase's REST API. https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest-api.html

Comment: @frank yes, but can you 'watch' for changes using the REST api from a Dart server? I see that the Firebase rest api can  now listen for events using EventSource/Server-Sent Events. Does Dart support that? Any examples?

Answer (score 2):

The library you reference ([firebase.dart](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-dart/)) is purely for client-side usage. For server-side usage, Firebase offers a [REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest-api.html). There are helper libraries for many languages, but not for Dart as far as I know. As it's REST, it seems to be very easy to interact with Firebase endpoints to get and put data.

You'll want to set up an [HttpServer](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io.HttpServer), of course, and then it's a matter of interacting with the Firebase endpoints using `http.put` and `http.read`.

Firebase's server-side streaming support via its REST API seems more involved. There doesn't seem to be many Dart folks using Firebase, certainly not the server-side stuff, and so you'll just have to work through getting your server to interact as the docs explain.

(If I get to that point myself, I'll report back and share my code, though all I care to do at the moment on the server is save some data from a Facebook authentication callback URL which my server reads in. Everything else Firebase is on the client side for me.)